# Connecting to 4D database in Power BI via ODBC

Tags: powerbi, 4d-database

Has anyone tried connecting to a 4D database from Power BI? I keep getting this error when I try to connect.

```
The field `Field Name` already exists in the record.
```

What's happening is that the 4D database columns all have spaces in there. I think that's causing the problem, maybe Power BI just reads the part before the space and saw another field with the same name before the space. E.g. "School Name" and "School Address".

Is there anyway to get around this? Due to this error PowerBI won't load the data.

Comment: Can you show us your sql queries and relevant parts of your schema?

Answer (score -2):

I think spaces are not the issue, because I had the same problem and my fields has no spaces.

I found some where else that you have to include: select*from *table-name*

And thats it...